# Как передать id строки в модальное окно php ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap

У меня есть таблица в которую я вывожу данные из бд. В таблице есть строки, на каждой строке выводится кнопка для подробного просмотра всех полей. При нажатию на кнопку открывается модальное окно boostrap, в окне я хочу выводить данные из строки. Проблема заключается в том что записи разные и их как то нужно различать, различать их нужно по id. Сейчас у меня возникла проблема с id, мне нужно передать id в модальное окно, чтобы я мог нажать на любую строку нажать и в модальном окне мне вывелась бы конкретная информация (проще говоря отобразить строку со всеми полями в модальном окне как показано на картинке.). 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Я хочу добиться чтобы id менялся в модальном окне.

```
`<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary prosm" name="id" id="one" value="<?=$field?>" >` // Переменная $field - хранит id строки. 
`$s = "SELECT %s FROM tovars where id='$id' ";`
```

Вот код

```
`<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!-- Заголовок модального окна -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Характеристики товара</h4>
      </div>
      <!-- Основное содержимое модального окна -->
    <?
        $translates  = [
        'id' => 'Id',
        'oblastnazn' => 'Область назначения',
        'proizvoditel' => 'Производитель',
        'name1' => 'Наименование',
        ];  

    $fields = array_keys($translates);
    //$id=$_POST['id'];
    $s = "SELECT %s FROM tovars where id='$id' ";
    //echo $s;

    $sql = sprintf($s, implode(',', $fields));

    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);

    $stmt->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($rows as $k=>$row){
 foreach($row as $ke=>$rrow){?>

  <table>
  <tr>
  <td style='width: 195px; height: 30px;'><?=$translates[$ke]?></td>
  <td  class='chenge' style='width: 180px; height: 30px;' data-id='<?=$row[id]?>' data-name='<?=$ke?>' > <?=$rrow?>
  </td><tr></table>
 <?}
}   
    ?>

<!-- Футер модального окна -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
      </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
```

нашел код который мне возможно поможет, скажите

```
// Прикручиваем к каждой ссылке onclick
....
echo '<a href="#" rel="popuprel2" class="popup" onclick="return linkclick(12);"><img src="'.$row['mini_img'].'"></a>';   // 12 это id ссылки
....
-------------------------------------
// Обработчик клика
function linkclick(id) {
   var dt = [];
   dt['linkid'] = id;
   $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/linkprocessor.php',
                data: dt,
                error: function(req, text, error) {
                          alert('Произошла ошибка AJAX: ' + text + ' | ' + error);
                },
                success: function (json) {
                          $('#popuprel2').show();   // Показываем модальное окно
                          $('#modaltext').text(json.data);      // Содержимое какого-то div в модальном окне заменяем на то, что пришло из PHP
                },
                dataType: "json"
   });
        return false;   // Обязательно возвращаем false, чтобы не сработал реальный переход по ссылке мнение свое "#"
}
--------------------------
Внутри файла linkprocessor.php
if (isset($_POST['linkid'])) {
        // Пришёл запрос AJAX
   ..... обрабатываем linkid, получая текст в $data
   echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));   // Пакуем $data в json и отправляем обратно клиенту в success
   exit();   // Обязательно должно быть (дабы не попортить json чем-нить)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

По коду у тебя сделано не корректно, если ты хочешь на стороне сервера наделать окон с информацией по ИДу, то надо сделать столько блоков с модальными окнами, сколько ИДов у тебя будет. Но это более менее когда у тебя не много такой строк. А если много, то вариант, отправки запроса на сервер, который вернет тебе json со структурой твоих полей, которые ты вставишь в окно с "подробной информацией", гораздо лучше.

А так, создаешь функцию

```
function moreInfo(id) {
   $('#myModal' + id).modal('open')
}
```

и подписываешь каждое свое поле на `onClick="moreInfo($id)"`